# What is the last Erlang Version requiring is_subtype

Tags: erlang

According to the [Erlang Types and Function Specifications](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html), to constrain the output type of a function in the `::` constraint can be used in the `when` part of the `-spec` attribute:

```
-spec id(X) -> X when X :: tuple().
```

For backwards compatibility it is also possible to use:

```
-spec id(X) -> X when is_subtype(X, tuple()).
```

But the use of is_subtype is discouraged (deprecated). What is the last Erlang Version requiring the use of is_subtype instead of ::?

Comment: If you're interested from the practical point of view, just use new notation without bothering

Comment: I need to support older Erlang versions and need to know, if i can use the current notation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `-spec id(X) -> X when X :: tuple().` does not compile with Erlang/OTP version R13B04 but does with R14B04. The syntax `-spec id(X) -> X when is_subtype(X, tuple()).` compiles with both R13B04 and R14B04. Therefore, I believe the answer to your question is Erlang/OTP R13B04.